# Is $J(V)$ just the symmetric algebra of the dual of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, vector-spaces, multilinear-algebra

Let us work over a fixed but arbitrary field $k$. So for example, all vectorspaces and algebras are implicitly over $k$.

Given a vectorspace $V$, we can build two (potentially) different commutative algebras equipped with a canonical inclusion of $V$ as a subspace. Namely:

- Let $S(V^*)$ denote the symmetric algebra of the dual of $V$.
- Let $J(V)$ be the least subalgebra $A$ (of the algebra of all functions $k \leftarrow V$) satisfying $A \supseteq V^*.$

By the universal property of the symmetric algebra, there's an algebra homomorphism $$J(V) \leftarrow S(V^*).$$ Its clearly surjective.

> **Question.** Is the above morphism always an isomorphism? If not, what is the usual terminology/notation for what I'm denoting $J(V)$?
>
> I'm interested in both the finite-dimensional case and the general case.

Comment: I am not sure what you have been asking, but in positive characteristic, $S^p(V)^*$ may not be isomorphic to $S^p(V^*)$ in a natural fashion.

Comment: I am confused about the definition of $S^*(V)$ what do you mean subject to the constraint that $S^*(V)$ includes V. Also when you say functions do you mean linear functions or all functions?

Comment: I do not know what does $S^*(V)$ mean, but regarding the other term, if you want to avoid characteristic zero, $S(V^*)\cong \Gamma (V)^*$ (divided power algebra) if it helps (at least in the finite dimensional case).

Comment: @Mohan, I'm not sure what $S^p(V)^*$ has to do with what I'm asking here...

Comment: @user45150, I've edited the definition to make it a bit more precise.

Comment: The symmetric algebra is a quotient of a free algebra, and as such is only bound by the commutativity relations of its generators. If your field is say finite, all your functionals will satisfy an equation of the form $X^q-X$, and this doesn't happen in the symmetric algebra.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, can you explain a little more? This seems to be related to the Frobenius endomorphism. But, I thought this was Frobenius function was only an endomorphism in prime characteristic. You seem to be saying that mere finiteness is enough...

Comment: Finite fields have prime characteristic.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, ahh right. That makes sense. So would it be fair to say that whenever the background field has non-zero characteristic, then $J(V)$ will necessarily be strictly more degenerate than $S^(V^*),$ even if the background field is infinite? Thanks for being patient with me; as you can probably tell, I know essentially nothing about field theory.

Comment: @goblin If $V$ is finite dimension, the map $S(V^*)\to J(V)$ has kernel if and only if the field is finite. Basically, $\mathbb{F}_q$ does not have enough points to differentiate different equations. I will write this up into an answer later today when I have more time.

Comment: @user45150, thanks. That sounds quite reasonable on the basis of what Pedro has said, although I can't quite see *why*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be the ground field. I claim that $S(V^*)\to J(V)$ is a bijection if and only if the ground field is infinite.

First note the map is always surjective.

Then by Pedro Tamaroff's comment, if the ground field is finite of order $q$ for any $x\in S(V^*)$, then image of $x^q-x$ is zero, and hence in this case the map is not injective.

We now assume that $k$ is infinite and we first assume that $V$ is finite dimensional. Pick a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ for $V$ and let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be its dual basis (i.e. $x_i(v_j)=1$ if $i=j$ and zero otherwise). Any element onf $S(V^*)$ can be expressed as a polynomial in the $x_i$. Let us have $g(x)\in S(V^*)$ and consider its image in $J(V)$, and call this image $h$. If $v=\sum_i a_i v_i\in V$, then $h(v)$ is given by evualating the polynomial $g$ at $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. As $k$ is infinite, as polynomials over infinite fields vanish identically if and only if they are zero, $g(x)\neq 0$ implies there is some $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ such that $g(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\neq 0$, and thus $h\neq 0$, so we have injectivity.

For infinite dimensional $V$, for any $s\in S(V^*)$, $s$ involves only finitely many linearly independent elements of $V^*$, $t_1,\ldots,t_m$. Consider a finite dimensional subspace of $V$, $W$, where $t_1|_W,\ldots,t_n|_W$ are linearly independent. Then the image of $s$ in $J(W)$ (a quotient of $J(V)$) is nonzero by the finite-dimensional case, so the image in $J(V)$ is nonzero, so again $S(V^*)\to J(V)$ is injective.

At some point I use the fact that if we have a polynomial over an infinite field, $f(x)$, then $f\equiv 0$ if and only if $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=0$ for all possible $a_i$. You seemed to express in the comments that you did not know how to do this. Can you see how to do this if $f$ is a polynomial in one variable? Then fixing all but one variable and letting the last vary, do you see how to do the general case by induction?

Comment: One last thought. The above answer is just really only the fact that polynomials over infinite fields are zero if and only if they are zero on all points.